# Calculate special integrals

Tags: integration

Prove:$$\int_0^1\frac{1-\cos x}{x} \, dx-\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\cos x}{x} \, dx=\gamma, \\ \gamma=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/2+\cdots+1/n-\ln n)$$

I try to use the Taylor expansion of $1-\cos x$ and exchange the order of 'integral sign' and 'sum sign', but I don't know how to deal with the latter integral.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3129759/real-analysis-methodologies-to-prove-int-x-infty-frac-costt-dt-gamm?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Ok,I see.Thank you!

Comment: Or see formula (3.20) in Ch. 2 of [Olver, 1974](https://www.google.com/search?q=Asymptotics+and+Special+Functions+F.W.J.+Olver&oq=Asymptotics+and+Special+Functions+F.W.J.+Olver&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUyBggAEEUYOTIGCAEQRRg8MgYIAhBFGDwyBggDEEUYPDIGCAQQLhhA0gEIMTY0N2owajGoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis :Sorry to disturb you.Are you a professor at the Michigan technology university?I am fortunate that a professor has answered my doubts. I am just a low-level undergraduate student in mathematic.

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis:Thank you again!

Comment: As you are an undergrad (and self-confessed noob), I suggest asking further general mathematics questions on math.stackexchange.com, due to the focus of MO being questions that arise in the course of original mathematics research. Best of luck with your studies!